# Tengo una db y la tabla la tengo en phpmyadmin no me inserta datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, phpmyadmin

CONEXION.PHP

```
<?php 
    $conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "fran","123","frankliber");
 ?>
```

---

FORMULARIO.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>-
<html>
<head>
    <title>Guardar</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formulario.css">

</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <form action="operacio_guardar.php" method="POST"><br/><br/><br/>
            <input type="text" REQUIRED name="matricula" placeholder="Número de matricula" value=""><br><br>
                <input type="text" REQUIRED name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre completo" value=""><br><br>
                <input type="text" REQUIRED name="periodo" placeholder="Periodo actual" value=""><br><br>
                <input type="text" REQUIRED name="biologia" placeholder="Nota biologia" value=""><br><br>
                <input type="text" REQUIRED name="sociales" placeholder="Nota sociales" value=""><br><br>
                <input type="text" REQUIRED name="etica" placeholder="Nota etica" value=""><br><br>
                <input type="text" REQUIRED name="artistica" placeholder="Nota artistica" value=""><br><br>
                <input type="text" REQUIRED name="edufisica" placeholder="Nota edu.fisica" value=""><br><br>
                <input type="text" REQUIRED name="religion" placeholder="Nota religión" value=""><br><br>
                <input type="text" REQUIRED name="castellano" placeholder="Nota castellano" value=""><br><br>
                <input type="text" REQUIRED name="matematicas" placeholder="Nota matematicas" value=""><br><br>
                <input type="text" REQUIRED name="tecnologia" placeholder="Nota tecnologia" value=""><br><br>
                <input type="text" REQUIRED name="ccpv" placeholder="Nota ccpv" value=""><br><br>
                <input type="text" REQUIRED name="fisica" placeholder="Nota física" value=""><br><br>
                <input type="text" REQUIRED name="quimica" placeholder="Nota quimica" value=""><br><br>
                <input type="text" REQUIRED name="observaciones" placeholder="observaciones" value="">

            <input class="boton" type="submit" value="Aceptar">
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

---

FORMULARIO.CSS

```
body{
    background-image: url("https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-3hDCx5wKrDA/UZATKWgw-UI/AAAAAAAACmo/Mwgj_sTrffk/s1600/Descargar+Pack+Fondos+de+escritorio+Animacion+HD+(306).jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.caja{
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
.boton{
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border:none;
}
.boton:hover{
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    border:none;
}
table{
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: white;


}
#campos{
}
```

---

OPERACION_GUARDAR.PHP

```
<?php 
    include("conexion.php");

        $matricula=$_POST['matricula'];
        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
        $periodo=$_POST['periodo'];
        $biologia=$_POST['biologia'];
        $sociales=$_POST['sociales'];
        $etica=$_POST['etica'];
        $artistica=$_POST['artistica'];
        $edufisica=$_POST['edufisica'];
        $religion=$_POST['religion'];
        $castellano=$_POST['castellano'];
        $matematicas=$_POST['matematicas'];
        $tecnologia=$_POST['tecnologia'];
        $ccpv=$_POST['ccpv'];
        $fisica=$_POST['fisica'];
        $quimica=$_POST['quimica'];
        $observaciones=$_POST['observaciones'];

        $query= "INSERT INTO estudiantes(matricula,nombre,periodo,biologia,sociales,etica,artistica,edufisica,religion,castellano,matematicas,tecnologia,ccpv,fisica,quimica,observaciones) VALUES('$matricula','$nombre','$periodo','$biologia','$sociales','$etica','$artistica','$edufisica','$religion'.'$castellano','$matematicas','$tecnologia','$ccpv','$fisica','$quimica','$observaciones')";

        $resultado = $conexion->query($query);

        if($resultado){
            echo "insercion existosa";
        }
        else{
            echo "insercion fallida";
        }
```

Comment: Arroja algún error ?

Comment: no, un error no no llega al proceso insertar, no alcanza a llegar, le puse un condicional y un else, que diga inserción fallida.

Comment: ¿Nos puedes ayudar con el error específico para así ayudarte?, pon:

`if (!$conexion->query($query)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}`

Puedes ver más información en este [enlace](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: vale no es un error, es un proceso que no se esta realizando el proceso que no se esta realizando es el INSERT INTO en la tabla usuarios2 que esta en la db llamada "frankliber", mi tabla es de 17 campos pero si yo modifico el código y hago otra tabla mas pequeña por ejemplo: con 4 campos si me inserta los datos, mientras que con mi tabla de 17 campos no

Answer (score 1):

---En tu archivo **operacio_guardar.php** tienes un punto(.) entre las variables '$religion'.'$castellano' habría que cambiarlo por una coma(,)

y finalmente para que se te imprima un error podrías agregar lo siguiente debajo de tu instrucción  `$query = "INSERT INTO ...`:

```
if (mysqli_query($conexion, $query)) {
            echo "insercion existosa";
        } else {
            echo "insercion fallida: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conexion);
        }
```

Con estos cambios ya debes poder ingresar los datos en tu tabla, cualquier comentario lo haces saber.

Comment: new mysqli es perfectamente válido para conectarse a la DB solo que es orientado a objetos así que por ahí no va el detalle

Comment: aquí esta la fuente oficial de la documentación de PHP que lo indica como válido http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.construct.php no deberías recomendar como fuente w3schools cuando se tiene la documentación oficial a la cual por cierto deberías revisar

Comment: Correcto, la verdad que php no es mi fuerte pero agradezco tu comentario, yo estaba en un error, lo que podría causar el problema es lo segundo que comente, de todas maneras hay que probarlo.

Comment: Efectivamente el uso de new mysqli es válido, yo creo que lo mejor sería primero que nada atrapar el mensaje de error con un **try catch** y así verificar cuál es el error, ya que por el campo de '$religion'.'$castellano', bien podría ser una columna concatenada, sería bueno que nos ayude con su mensaje de error específico.

Comment: hasta que el OP no especifique de manera perfectamente clara la intención de la pregunta no se deberían postear respuestas que lo que hacen al momento es estar adivinando

Comment: Efectivamente @AlfredoPaz

Comment: vale no es un error, es un proceso que no se esta realizando el proceso que no se esta realizando es el INSERT INTO en la tabla usuarios2 que esta en la db llamada "frankliber", mi tabla es de 17 campos pero si yo modifico el código y hago otra tabla mas pequeña por ejemplo: con 4 campos si me inserta los datos, mientras que con mi tabla de 17 campos no

Comment: osea mi código esta bien porque con mi tabla de cuatro campos si me inserta los datos, pero si yo creo una tabla de 17 campos, y en html agrego los 17 input no me inserta los datos me manda directamente el ECHO "inserción fallida"

Comment: Amigos la verdad es que no se de que otra manera explicarlo agradezco su paciencia.

Comment: Y si tenía un error acá  '$religion'.'$castellano', gracias @HoracioEspinosaBarceló ya lo corregí.

Comment: lo que pienzo al respecto es que se te esta escapando algo , ya que no hay ninguna restriccion para el numero de campos a insertar en php , so revisa bien tu codigo recuerda cualquier diferencia de letra minuscula o mayuscula seria un motivo revisa bien tu codigo